# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F5694708-88FE-4B35-BABF-E56162D5FBC8}

Tags: com

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F5694708-88FE-4B35-BABF-E56162D5FBC8} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).  I am receiving is error while creating Group Policy Object, m using Inerop.GPMGMTLib  and have ensured that project build is x86, however both on 32 as well as 64 bit VM machine, it is getting failed. Its very urgent, can anyone has idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code indicates it clearly: COM class is not available for you. Double check this by checking registry under `HKCU\CLSID\{identifier}` and if information is there, check whether COM class references valid binary.

If the file is missing, it has to be installed or re-registered from proper location etc. If the file is present, it might be missing a mandatory dependency module or otherwise it fails to start.

Comment: I am referring the Interop.GPMGMTLib dll in my solution. However, realize that I am working on client side os not a server os. Thanks